# How can I know the version of an installed app?

Tags: apps

I installed an app and I would like to know what is it version.
In the app menu no command is available to see the version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the Store, select downloads from the menu, and go to History, it will show you the latest version of an app you have installed.  I know this works in 8.1.1 DP, but I haven't checked it in 8.0.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get is post a comment in the Store, wait it appear anew check the version it says you are using.

[image]
  [image]

As you can see I posted a comment using the version 2.7.8.236 while the current version is 2014.822.316.3341.

Those versions are not extracted from the same place (I think). But this particular developer use the build number as reference. In this case 236 in my comment and 316 in the app details page.

Answer (score 1):

You can only ever have [one version of an app deployed at once](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/4002/106) and you can find the currently released version number by going to the store, browsing to the app in question, swipe across to the details tab, and you will see the date of last update, and the current version number

Comment: That will give you the latest available version of the app, though, not necessarily the version you have installed right now.

Comment: @Indrek I think the closer you can get to that is post a new comment on the Store. It will show what app version you are referring.

Comment: Whilst it only shows the released version - you can determine if you don't have that version, as it will have an "[Update]" button. With 8.1, apps can be set to auto-update as well, so it will *most likely* be the installed version.

Comment: @VitorCanova That's a nice trick, you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Indrek did. Unsure if is really useful since comments take time to appear.